# 'super' object has no attribute 'set_context'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I upgrade Django version from 1.11 to 3.2 and upgrade the installed python.

I am facing an error at this line

**super().set_context(serializer_field)**

Below is the Full class code.

```
class UniqueForProjectValidator(UniqueValidator):

    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        super().set_context(serializer_field)
        self.project = serializer_field.parent.context['project']

    def filter_queryset(self, value, queryset):
        queryset = queryset.filter(project=self.project)
        return super().filter_queryset(value, queryset)
```

Here is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception      
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 82, in partial_update
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 67, in update
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 220, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 419, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 476, in to_internal_value       
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 799, in run_validation
    return super().run_validation(data)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 569, in run_validation
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 587, in run_validators
    validator.set_context(self)
  File "C:\Users\arauf\Desktop\innerzone\NewCode\InnerZone-Backend\core\utils.py", line 213, in set_context
    super().set_context(serializer_field)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'set_context'
```

Comment: Anyone here to explain the issue?

Comment: Have you read the relevant documents to see if something changed between versions?

Comment: Yes, I saw the version changes but did not find any related changes.

Comment: Can you add a full stack trace for the error please.

Comment: You'd think they'd mention deprecating or outright getting rid of a method at least in passing somewhere

Comment: I searched "django set_context" and this is the first thing that came up: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.11-announcement/

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tool to delegate Google to strangers on the internet. Please read [ask]

Comment: I added the full stack trace @DeanElliott

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have possibly upgraded Django Rest Framework as well however on Django Rest Frameworks GitHub page, the method `set_context` does not exist. So your error is telling you, the method `set_context` on the parent class `UniqueValidator` does not exist.

See their GitHub page [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/validators.py#L33).